# Get Pinterest RSS feed for board with special characters

Tags: pinterest

Normally, to get the RSS feed for a Pinterest board, you simply add ".rss" to the end of the URL.

For example, for the board at `http://www.pinterest.com/philchairez/mega-man-x/`, you can get the RSS feed from `http://www.pinterest.com/philchairez/mega-man-x.rss`.

If a board has a special character in its name, usually, it seems like Pinterest has simply removed the special characters from the assigned URL.

For example, this board is named "film + music + books + games" and its URL is `http://www.pinterest.com/claramechelle/film-music-books-games/` (notice that the '+' characters are excluded).

Another example: "Kids diy games + musical instruments", `http://www.pinterest.com/sammijjohno/kids-diy-games-musical-instruments/`

Getting the RSS feeds for these boards works as expected:
`http://www.pinterest.com/claramechelle/film-music-books-games.rss`
`http://www.pinterest.com/sammijjohno/kids-diy-games-musical-instruments.rss`

However, URLs for some boards sometimes include the URL encoding of a special character. For example, this board is named "Dungeons + Dragons":
`http://www.pinterest.com/lizardskingirl/dungeons-%2B-dragons/`

And this board is named "Game Art + UI/HUD":
`http://www.pinterest.com/portableneko/game-art-%2B-uihud/`

Adding ".rss" to these URLs does not work:
`http://www.pinterest.com/lizardskingirl/dungeons-%2B-dragons.rss`
`http://www.pinterest.com/portableneko/game-art-%2B-uihud.rss`

You'll just get redirected to the user's board list. If you try to simply remove the special character like the other URLs, you'll get a 404.

Does anyone know how to get the RSS feed for boards like this?

Comment: The URLs are formatted like code since you're not allowed to post more than two URLs as a new user.

Comment: Something new about it? I raised a ticket to pinterest but the answer was they don't support RSS feeds.

Comment: Note that some of the example boards I listed now return 404 because the users that owned them have since removed those boards, but the problem I describe remains. I'll try to come up with new examples later, if I remember.

Comment: Running into the same exact issue, trying to get the RSS feed for a board with `%2B` in the URL. Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: @DelPiero Nope, I never figured it out

Answer (score 3):

Try this

http://pinterest.com/[username]/feed.rss

For example, my username is "sharp", so my RSS feed can be found at:

http://pinterest.com/sharp/feed.rss

Source:
http://www.quora.com/Does-Pinterest-have-plans-to-allow-for-RSS-feeds-for-a-users-specific-pinboards

Comment: "feed://" protocol does not work.  Replaced with "http://" and the server returned the feed I intended.

Comment: This is not really related to my question. I was specifically interested in RSS feeds for specific boards, not users. Also, "sharp" doesn't contain any "special" (non-alphanumeric) characters.

Comment: Did Pinterest recently drop or modify RSS support? I had it working, but last night noticed it had stopped. I will investigate further, your sharp/feed.rss worked right now when I clicked it. Even the javascript I was using on my homepage may need updating or the PHP, the problem may be on my end but it worked for years.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the rss feed if you replace the character encoding with the actual '+', and then tack '.rss' to the end:

http://www.pinterest.com/portableneko/game-art-%2B-uihud   becomes:
http://www.pinterest.com/portableneko/game-art-+-uihud.rss

Answer (score 0):

Renaming a board doesn't change its internal name, so if you have renamed a board see if you can remember its original name and generate the `.rss` URL from that.